# Reading a specific file from a zip with multiple files

Tags: pandas, dataframe, zip

```
url="https://s-media.nyc.gov/agencies/dcp/assets/files/zip/data-tools/bytes/nychdb_22q2_csv.zip"
housing_production_since2010_df = pd.read_csv(url)
```

running the code above I get the following error:
Multiple files found in compressed zip file `['Housing Database - Data Dictionary.xlsx', 'HousingDB_post2010.csv']`

how do I specify which csv to read in?

I tried

```
url="https://s-media.nyc.gov/agencies/dcp/assets/files/zip/data-tools/bytes/nychdb_22q2_csv.zip"
housing_production_since2010_df = pd.read_csv(url)
```

I was hoping to read in `HousingDB_post2010.csv`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the approach that I would use when reading a single csv file from remote zipfile containing multiple files:

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO

with requests.get(url) as resp, ZipFile(BytesIO(resp.content)) as zip_:
    housing_data = pd.read_csv(zip_.open('HousingDB_post2010.csv'))
```

Result:

```
  Job_Number    Job_Type    ResidFlag       NonresFlag                 Job_Status CompltYear PermitYear  ClassAInit  ClassAProp  ClassANet  HotelInit  HotelProp  OtherBInit  OtherBProp  Units_CO  Boro      BIN         BBL AddressNum           AddressSt                          Occ_Init                          Occ_Prop Bldg_Class                                                                                                       Job_Desc   DateFiled         DatePermit  DateLstUpd         DateComplt ZoningDst1 ZoningDst2 ZoningDst3 SpeclDst1 SpeclDst2 Landmark  FloorsInit  FloorsProp Enlargemnt                        Ownership       CenBlock10   CenTract10    BCTCB2010  BCT2010 NTA2010                               NTAName10       CenBlock20   CenTract20    BCTCB2020  BCT2020 NTA2020                         NTAName20 CDTA2020                                         CDTAName20 CommntyDst CouncilDst SchSubDist SchCommnty SchElmntry SchMiddle FireCmpany FireBattln FireDivsn PolicePcnt PL_FIRM07 PL_PFIRM15   Latitude  Longitude          GeomSource                                                              DCPEdited Version
0  102138820  Alteration  Residential                   5. Completed Construction       2012       2008         6.0        19.0       13.0          0          0          46          38      57.0     1  1055472  1018390020         19    WEST  103 STREET  Residential: Not Specified (RES)  Residential: Not Specified (RES)         HS                                                                                                                 2001-02-09  1/11/2008 0:00:00  2015-02-20  7/20/2012 0:00:00         R8                                                            5.0         5.0             Private For-Profit: Corporation  360610189001002  36061018900  10189001002  1018900    MN12                         Upper West Side  360610189001002  36061018900  10189001002  1018900  MN0703  Upper West Side-Manhattan Valley     MN07          MN07 Upper West Side (CD 7 Approximation)        107         07        3_1         03        541        95       E076         11        03        024                       40.796735 -73.962554  Lat/Lon geosupport  otherb_init/classa_init/classa_prop/hotel_prop/hotel_init/otherb_prop    22Q2
1  102151083  Alteration  Residential                   5. Completed Construction       2011       2002         7.0         9.0        2.0          0          0           0           0       9.0     1  1076939  1003860063        215    EAST    3 STREET  Residential: Not Specified (RES)  Residential: Not Specified (RES)         D7                                                                                                                 2001-06-14  1/25/2002 0:00:00  2013-03-21  8/31/2011 0:00:00        R8B                                                            4.0         6.0              Private For-Profit: Individual  360610026012001  36061002601  10026012001  1002601    MN28                         Lower East Side  360610026012001  36061002601  10026012001  1002601  MN0303                      East Village     MN03   MN03 Lower East Side-Chinatown (CD 3 Equivalent)        103         02        1_3         01        502        81       E028         04        01        009                       40.722607 -73.982247  Lat/Lon geosupport                                                                           22Q2
2  102284172  Alteration  Residential  Non-Residential  5. Completed Construction       2016       2001         1.0         1.0        0.0          0          0           0           0       1.0     1  1008505  1005300132         57  GREAT JONES STREET  Residential: Not Specified (RES)            Commercial: Retail (C)         K2  EXTENSION OF EXISTING BUILDING. MODIFICA TION TO CERTIFICATE OF OCCUPAMC .  EXTIMATED COST IS NOW $75,000.00.  2001-03-20  6/13/2001 0:00:00  2012-06-15   1/7/2016 0:00:00       C6-1                                                Yes         0.0         2.0             Private For-Profit: Partnership  360610055021001  36061005502  10055021001  1005502    MN23                            West Village  360610055021002  36061005502  10055021002  1005502  MN0202                 Greenwich Village     MN02      MN02 Greenwich Village-SoHo (CD 2 Equivalent)        102         01        2_1         02        874        94       L009         06        01        009                       40.726393 -73.992359  Lat/Lon geosupport                                                            classa_init    22Q2
3  102284804  Alteration  Residential                   5. Completed Construction       2022       2001         4.0         4.0        0.0          0          0           0           0       4.0     1  1008323  1005260062        174     BLEECKER STREET  Residential: Not Specified (RES)  Residential: Not Specified (RES)         S4                                                                  Apply for new C of O with minor construction.  2001-03-21   8/1/2001 0:00:00  2021-10-19  4/20/2022 0:00:00       C1-5       R7-2                                                 0.0         5.0             Private For-Profit: Corporation  360610065003003  36061006500  10065003003  1006500    MN23                            West Village  360610065003005  36061006500  10065003005  1006500  MN0202                 Greenwich Village     MN02      MN02 Greenwich Village-SoHo (CD 2 Equivalent)        102         03        2_2         02        874        94       L009         06        01        006                       40.728743 -74.000837  Lat/Lon geosupport              classa_init/otherb_init/hotel_init/otherb_prop/hotel_prop    22Q2
4  102292010  Alteration  Residential  Non-Residential  5. Completed Construction       2022       2001         0.0         2.0        2.0          0          0           0           0       2.0     1  1002351  1001960027         84       WALKER STREET   Commercial: Not Specified (COM)   Commercial: Not Specified (COM)         M1                                                                                                                 2001-03-27  4/20/2001 0:00:00  2019-05-20  3/25/2022 0:00:00       M1-5                                                            0.0         4.0             Private For-Profit: Corporation  360610031001001  36061003100  10031001001  1003100    MN24  SoHo-TriBeCa-Civic Center-Little Italy  360610031001001  36061003100  10031001001  1003100  MN0102              Tribeca-Civic Center     MN01  MN01 Financial District-Tribeca (CD 1 Equivalent)        101         01        2_1         02        530        87       L001         01        01        005                       40.718334 -74.001400  Lat/Lon geosupport              otherb_init/otherb_prop/hotel_init/classa_init/hotel_prop    22Q2
```

Details

Use the `requests` module to fetch the content of remote zip file as bytes then create a `ZipFile` object from the buffer. Now assuming you already know the name of the file, use the `open` method to read the single csv file to create a dataframe

Answer (score 1):

This ended up working for me.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from zipfile import ZipFile
from io import BytesIO

r = requests.get("https://s-media.nyc.gov/agencies/dcp/assets/files/zip/data-tools/bytes/nychdb_22q2_csv.zip")
files = ZipFile(BytesIO(r.content))
housing_production_since2010_df = pd.read_csv(files.open("HousingDB_post2010.csv"))
```